# What's the type of cls introduced by @classmethod

Tags: python-typing

I have a simple class `C` with a `@classmethod` and a dataclass `DC`:

```py
@dataclass
class DC:
    c_class: ???

class C:
    @classmethod
    def hello(cls) -> DC:
        return DC(cls)
```

What's the type of `cls` ? I need to declare it as part of `c_class` in the `@dataclass DC`, so I also need to specify the exact type of it.

Comment: It's a class method on `C`, so... `Type[C]`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe is correct! Here is the relevant documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type

Comment: you would here define it as `c_class: Type['C']` - wrap in quotes to forward declare it, since the implementation of C is only defined in following lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all who commented on the question.

The answer is indeed:

```py
@dataclass
class DC:
    c_class: Type['C']  # or Type[C], if C is already defined
```

I verified, *mypy* and *PyCharm* like it and *PyCharm* even detects the proper class members available to `c_class`, as I needed. I'm building a strongly-typed software, comments and hints to solve this issue were appreciated.